# Using 'HttpContext.Current.Cache' safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, service, thread-safety

I am using `Cache` in a web service method like this:

```
var pblDataList = (List<blabla>)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("pblDataList");

if (pblDataList == null)
{
    var PBLData = dc.ExecuteQuery<blabla>(@"SELECT blabla");

    pblDataList = PBLData.ToList();

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("pblDataList", pblDataList, null,
        DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15)),
        Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
}
```

But I wonder, is this code thread-safe? The web service method is called by multiple requesters. And more then one requester may attempt to retrieve data and add to the `Cache` at the same time while the cache is empty.

The query takes 5 to 8 seconds. Would introducing a lock statement around this code prevent any possible conflicts? (I know that multiple queries can run simultaneously, but I want to be sure that only one query is running at a time.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cache object is thread-safe **but `HttpContext.Current` will not be available from background threads.**  This may or may not apply to you here, it's not obvious from your code snippet whether or not you are actually using background threads, but in case you are now or decide to at some point in the future, you should keep this in mind.

If there's any chance that you'll need to access the cache from a background thread, then use [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) instead.

In addition, although individual operations on the cache are thread-safe, sequential lookup/store operations are obviously not atomic.  Whether or not you *need* them to be atomic depends on your particular application.  If it could be a serious problem for the same query to run multiple times, i.e. if it would produce more load than your database is able to handle, or if it would be a problem for a request to return data that is immediately overwritten in the cache, then you would likely want to place a lock around the entire block of code.

However, in most cases you would really want to profile first and see whether or not this is actually a problem.  Most web applications/services don't concern themselves with this aspect of caching because they are stateless and it doesn't matter if the cache gets overwritten.

Comment: I don't use background threads, it's just web service calls. By the way, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The retrieving and adding operations are not being treated as an atomic transaction. If you need to prevent the query from running multiple times, you'll need to use a lock.

(Normally this wouldn't be much of a problem, but in the case of a long running query it can be useful to relieve strain on the database.)

Comment: This really depends.  In a high-throughput environment, the additional load on the database might not be as big a deal as the request-throttling that results from this kind of locking.  In *most* cases I'd say that you're right, but each case has to be evaluated individually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Add` should be thread-safe - i.e. it won't error if `Add` gets called twice with the same key, but obviously the query might *execute* twice.

Another question, however, is *is the data thread-safe*. There is no guarantee that each `List<blabla>` is isolated - it depends on the cache-provider. The in-memory cache provider stores the objects directly, so there is a risk of collisions if any of the threads edit the data (add/remove/swap items in the list, or change properties of one of the items). However, with a *serializing* provider you should be fine. Of course, this then demands that `blabla` is serializable...

Comment: Could you share a link to serializing your object for cache? I was trying to cache a data table at work for a web screen that filters some data. I was told the server load would be to much. Do you know of any articles that talk about caching and serializing as well as server load? I could not find anything specific while Googling.

Comment: @kcbeard firstly, once cached: **do not mutate** a `DataTable`. Now that is out of the way: how big is the data? What volume of rows?

Comment: Anywhere from a few hundred rows to 5k max. A dozen columns with date-time, int and var-char data types. Common sense told me to not use view state and SO backed me up. I was under an assumption only a few users per application instance would be accessing it so at first I used Current.Session, then it was brought up the server load being to much was so I thought Current.Cache (app wide). I mean maybe a stored procedure flexible enough to deal with all filtering would be the best route. But either way I want to know more about caching security, best practices, pitfalls ect.

Comment: I havent found a good article with anything specific to current.session ot current.cache security practices & pitfalls. I found a lot of one time things here and there and common opinions, do not cache large data, do not use session you are vulnerable to SQL replay attacks. I am a Junior Dev just trying to get it right the first time around, and already have figured out the workplace will do it the way that they are most comfortable with and not always the best way. I also realize everyone has an idea of what to and no to do. So I feel lucky to be getting your time and advise Marc.

Comment: Btw, I used your windows service installer class at my last job so, Thank you :)

Comment: @kcbeard as long as you treat the cache as just data (not state), I'd just use that, oersonally

Comment: I cache the first/ or base data table (m_DTBase). Then I make a copy (m_DTInUse) and use the copy to apply the users changes. (by date/date range, money, company, sub company, employee's ect...) I allow user to reset the data and it just recalls the original data, removes the DTInUse and copy's the original again. Is this not a safe way of doing it? It works really quick and well locally in development, could their be pitfalls in production?

Comment: @kcbeard hmmm... That would depend on a lot. Personally, I'd only use the cache for reference data in most cases - not for staging transactional behaviour

Comment: I didnt mention, not sure if it matters but the changes to the data (DTInUse) are not anything that will be saved to the database, only for viewing purposes and to retieve a RowID on user click event. Not trying to say I am correct, just trying to let you see the picture better so I can get a feel on weather or not I am headed in the right direction. Like I said, I am somewhat new to this. Also as to the question this has to do with safe cache usage.